# Kotlin generic type class as function parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics

How to pass parametr to function and then use it as generic type ?

```
 private fun createRequest(data: Data, class: Class<out UploaderTask>): OneTimeWorkRequest {
    return OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<class>().build()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer

```
private inline fun <reified T : UploaderTask>createRequest(data: Data): OneTimeWorkRequest {
    return OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<T>()
        .setInputData(data)
        .build()
}
```